Regarding the voltage in the resonant circuit of a Class F amplifier



When checking the operation, the secondary resonant circuit discharges.
When I checked with ADS, I confirmed that the voltage was not high enough to cause a discharge at 150V or less.
Regarding the voltage in the resonant circuit of a class F amplifier
When checking the operation, the secondary resonant circuit discharges.
I checked with ADS and confirmed that the voltage is not high enough to discharge below 150V, so I performed the experiment after confirming that.
I have also seen a description that the voltage becomes infinite in a series resonant circuit.
Please let me know if there are any precautions to take regarding the secondary and tertiary resonant circuits in a class F amplifier.
Operating conditions
Frequency: 100MHz
Target Output Power: 100W
Sincerely yours

Show a schematic.

Hearth
I added a circuit diagram.

To lower the Q, L205 is changed from 110 to 52nH and C219 is changed from 4.7 to 12pF (using a variable capacitor), and to consider heat dissipation, the order of L205 and C219 is C219-L205-GND.
I tried the above and it started to discharge.

By further reducing the resonant Q, the discharge no longer occurred.
Q=1/R*√(L/C)
